# Should we use the Neo4J internal id?

Tags: neo4j

We are currently working with a Neo4j database, and we need some kind of id to identify nodes.

For example we have functions like CurrentUserHasAccess(NodeId)

On other Stackoverflow posts I read that it's a bad idea to use the internal neo4j-identifier, because it can change over time. However I think that's not an issue when we do not use this id to link data.

However I cannot seem to find any official sources about this topic.

I would like to use this ID because then we do not need to worry about uniqueness, and more importantly indexing.

Comment: To the point about uniqueness you can add a unique constraint in Neo4j which would ensure that for you (that also adds an index for performance).  In the Ruby neo4j gem we automatically add a UUID to all nodes using Ruby's `SecureRandom.uuid` method

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the unique constraint is limited to one label at the time. So we should do this for each label. and each time we request something by id use a label.

Comment: That's correct, it would need to be attached to a label.  If you wanted a globally unique ID then you could also use one global label in addition to whatever labels you're already using and attach the constraint to that.  Of course as you say, you'd need to make sure to use that label in your query in order to hit the index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right that it is generally not recommended to use the internal Neo4j node IDs. This is mainly because if a node gets deleted, its original internal ID may get recycled/reused. If you're looking for a quick and elegant solution to this, have a look at the UUID module of the GraphAware Framework here https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid and let us know if it works for you.