# Global indexes in Neo

Tags: neo4j

In our company, we return a list of IDs to clients through a web service. The IDs are unique across the system. They invoke other web services passing the IDs. We don't always know the label of the ID we receive.

This does not perform:

```
MATCH(n {id:{my_id}) ...
```

While we have indexes on almost all label types, this query has no label and as thus does not use an index as far as I can tell.

Is it a bad idea to add a label called "GLOBAL" (or whatever) to all nodes so we can put a unique constraint on GLOBAL.id?  Then the query above could be

```
MATCH(n: GLOBAL{id:{my_id}})...
```

and perform nicely.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Neo4j's internal ID to identify your resources, but it's not best practice, see [Should we use the Neo4J internal id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753560/should-we-use-the-neo4j-internal-id)

This is how to get a node using his neo4j's internal id:

```
START n=node({my_id}) return n
```

It's really faster than a MATCH clause, because here your query directly starts with one node, and doesn't have to filter a property accross a set of nodes, because it's internal id.

If you can handle the internal id limitations, it's the solution you are looking for.

Comment: We have stopped using the internal ID (especially when sharing with clients) per best practice suggestions.