# Cypher match a node but allow the relationship to be optional

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this `(a {...})-[r]->(b)`

In my query, I always want 'a'.  I will take `r` and `b` if I can get them.

I tried

```
optional match (a {...})-[r]->(b)
```

but when `r` or `b` are not present the entire match collapses.

This works:

```
optional match (a {...})
optional match (a)-[r]->(b)
```

clunky and hacky.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use labels Tony, otherwise cypher has to scan the whole db for your nodes.

Comment: @MichaelHunger, I pared the example down for the specific question. But yeah, we just learned that the hard way as we scaled from test data more realistic data... everything stopped. We figured it out and got things working. I'd appreciate hearing your wisdom about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710578/global-indexes-in-neo

Answer (score 3):

You can split your query into two parts, the optional one, and the non-optional one:

```
Match (a:Label {...})
Optional Match (a)-[r]->(b) with a,r,b
//Do whatever you want with a,r and b here
```

Using this, you will have `a` for sure, and optionally, `r` and `b`.