# Neo4j match node with Id and create relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have a requirement to match two existing nodes with a specific Id and then create a relationship between these nodes. 
Below is my cypher. But when I execute this , I always get no changes done .

```
MATCH(i:`Mechanical Component`)
where ID(i)=9912
with(i)
match(d:Features{name:"Mechanical Component"})
with(d)
where ID(d)=9934
MERGE (i)-[:FEATURES]->(d)
```

Comment: Why do you match the `Features` node on both `id` and `name`? Are you sure the 2 are consistent? You also lose `i` at the second `WITH`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Frank Pavageau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565285/neo4j-match-node-with-id-and-create-relationship#comment64521956_38565285) said in the comments, you made an error in your query by not passing i with d in tha second `WITH`clause. Here is the corrected query you need:

```
MATCH(i:Mechanical Component)
where ID(i)=9912
with(i)
match(d:Features{name:"Mechanical Component"})
with(d,i)
where ID(d)=9934
MERGE (i)-[:FEATURES]->(d)
```

Keep in mind that using the internal id is really not recommended since it's generated and may change (see [Should we use the Neo4J internal id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753560/should-we-use-the-neo4j-internal-id)). You should probably use your own unique ID (with constraints) and match your node using this ID.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not find any difference in the cypher you have provided and mine. How do I carry the i in the second match.Sorry about the trivial question but I am new and somehow feel neo4j documentation is not delving into these details.