# How to update relation details in Neo4j using cypher query?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, neo4j

```
data= {
              "id": 1,
               "name": "samuel",
               "Manager": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "manager1",
                        "approvers": [325,134],

                            }
                      ]
                    }
```

FOR this data object , we did the add function using a similar given cypher query in Neo4j

```
        query = "CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (users:user) ASSERT users.name IS UNIQUE";

        return cypher(
            {
                "query": query
            }
        ).then(function () {
                query = "CREATE (user:user{ name:"samuel "})
                    "RETURN user";
                action = "create";
                return cypher(
                    {
                        "query": query,

                    });
            }).then(function (data) {

               userId = data[0].user._id;

                return Promise.each(data.manager, function (entry) {

                    query = "MATCH (user: user) WHERE id(user) = " + userId + " " +
                        " OPTIONAL MATCH (managerApprovers:user) WHERE id(managerApprovers) IN [325,134] " +
                        "CREATE (manager: managernode {name: "manager1"})<-[:HAS_MANAGER]-(user) " +
                        "FOREACH (a IN CASE WHEN managerApprovers IS NOT NULL THEN [managerApprovers] ELSE [] END | " +
                        "CREATE (managerApprovers)<-[:HAS_MANAGE_APPROVER]-(managernode)) RETURN user,managernode";

                    return cypher(
                        {
                            "query": query,

                        }).then(function (data) {
                             {
                res.action = action;
                res.result = data;
                return res;
            });
    }
```

if we want to update the user name along with updating the manager details and the relation HAS_MANAGE_APPROVER,HAS_MANAGER how is it performed in Neo4j

Answer (score 1):

You have to `MATCH` the relation, store it in a variable and then `SET` the property you want:

```
Match (a:firstNode)-[relation:MY_RELATIONSHIP]->(b:secondNode)
SET relation.variable="Foo"
```

Keep in mind that using neo4j internal ID is not recommended, see [Should we use the Neo4J internal id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753560/should-we-use-the-neo4j-internal-id)