# Neo4j internal ID reusing and dbms.ids.reuse.types.override property

Tags: neo4j

[There is a well know issue with internal Neo4j ID usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753560/should-we-use-the-neo4j-internal-id):

> ...it is generally not recommended to use the internal Neo4j node IDs.
>   This is mainly because if a node gets deleted, its original internal
>   ID may get recycled/reused

Neo4j can reuse these IDs so we can't rely on this mechanism in this case.

Some time ago Neo4j introduced a new property - [`dbms.ids.reuse.types.override`](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.ids.reuse.types.override)

> Specified names of id types (comma separated) that should be reused.
>   Currently only 'node' and 'relationship' types are supported.

Looks like with a help of this property we can disable ID reusing. Is it correct ?  If so, is it safe to use internal Neo4j ID in this case ? Also, does it supporting in Neo4j Community Edition or only at Neo4j Enterprise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read things correctly that setting does exactly the opposite of what you would like to use it for. It's an Enterprise Edition setting that allows easier reclaim of space. The answer in the post you refer to is still 100% valid. Do not refer to internal IDs. If you need a reference, work with a unique constraint and generate a UUID if none of the properties can be used.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Yes, exactly..but how about removing `NODE` or `RELATIONSHIP` or both of them from this property value in order to exclude  types that should be reused ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that's what you're implying :-). It would come with all kinds of penalties (your databasefiles would grow seriously if you have a high rate of deletes and inserts for example). Which is the reason you want that "on" in EE. Also (version) migrations/upgrades are still not guaranteed to keep the IDs intact. There's nothing that guarantees that ... and that I think is the point (also made in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X786c-SbW6w).

Comment: thanks. Sorry for this next question but is it your asumption or the information I can trust ?

Comment: I'm looking at the internal Neo4j documentation about this (and quoting from that) right now. Also ... the man in the video is THE authority on the subjects he talks about. So don't take it just from me.

Comment: Thanks. This is really bad because I can't switch to GUID for example and looks like there is no option in Neo4j for sequense value generation

Comment: Sorry ... but you'll have to elaborate. Why would a completely random generation of internal IDs (with no guaranteed order or sequence) work for you but something like UUID not ? What exactly do you need ? Is it that you need to guarantee sequential creation of nodes and then need them in order of creation ? If you can explain your use-case there will be someone with a solution !

Comment: Sure. The biggest issue is the application urls. I have to place id there.. pretty similar how StackOverflow does and my url with GUID there looks pretty bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145044/discussion-between-tom-geudens-and-alexanoid).